# "BeanLocator is null for servlet context", when using imported service.jar

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I am including the `service.jar` from one portlet (let's call it `Portlet A`), into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of another client Portlet, so that the client one can use the `*LocalServiceUtil`. Note that this is a thing I've done successfully a lots of times before.

But int this case, I'm getting this runtime exception when calling the LocalServiceUtil:

```
[PortletBeanLocatorUtil:38] BeanLocator is null for servlet context [Portlet A's portlet-name]
```

I'm almost sure there's something wrong with the project properties or build configuration of portlet A, but I'm not sure where to look at. The Liferay Forum is full of BeanLocator related problems, but each one has another solution

Both projects were designed and deployed for the same Liferay SDK and Tomcat Server versions.

Any ideas to fix the BeanLocator issue?

Answer (score 0):

The *service.jar includes only the signatures of the services from portlet A i.e the *LocalService and *Service interfaces, the model interfaces and util classes (and generally everything that resides in the service folder, under docroot, of the project tree) and not the implementation classes.
Therefore for this to work both portlets have to be deployed at the same time in the server (otherwise the implementation classes will not be found).
If this also the case you could change the liferay-plugin-package.properties file of portlet B and add portlet A as a required deployment context. This will inject the service.jar of the latter automatically.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. But i'm afraid this is not my case, as I have both webapps deployed in the same tomcat. any other ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried to add the second portlet as a required deployment context in the first's liferay-plugin-package.properties?

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I cannot do this test right now. I finally followed another workaround: Instead of using portletA-services in Portlet B, im' importing and using portletB-services in Portlet A, which works fine by the way. In the first chance, I'll do try your suggestion, and will report back, but this will have to wait a bit. Thanx for your help though!